# covariance of two correlated integrated brownian motions

Tags: integration, brownian-motion

Assume we have two integrated Brownian Motions

$\int_0^tf(t)dW_t$ and $\int_0^tg(t)dY_t$

where the $d$-dimensional Brownian Motions $W$ and $Y$ are correlated according to the positive semi-definite matrix $C$

$dW_tdY_t=Cdt$

I am trying to calculate the Covariance process of the sum of these two integrals. So far I have

$<\int_0^tf(t)dW_t+\int_0^tg(t)dY_t,\int_0^tf(t)dW_t+\int_0^tg(t)dY_t>\\
=\int_0^tf^2(t)dt+\int_0^tg^2(t)dt+2<\int_0^tf(t)dW_t,\int_0^tg(t)dY_t>$

Now my question is how the last expression looks like?

Comment: $$\left\langle\int_0^tf(s)dW_s,\int_0^tg(s)dY_s\right\rangle=C\int_0^tf(s)g(s)ds$$